# ChartJS 2.7.3 stacked bar chart with overlap

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a bar chart which has two overlapping bars and the other one would be stacked. Here's a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: stacked overlapping bar chart]

I was able to create the following based on examples I found, but the problem with the example is that e.g. in x1 the stacked bar should in value 15 because "First" value is 10 and "Second" value is 5, but now those are overlapping too.

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1ret02b/

```
var data = {
  labels: ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "First",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [10, 20, 30],
    xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
    //stack: 'stack 0'
  },
  {
    label: "Second",
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [5, 7, 9],
    xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
    //stack: 'stack 0'

  },
  {
    label: "Third",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [5, 30, 35],
    xAxisID: "bar-x-axis2",
  }]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      id: "bar-x-axis1",
      barThickness: 30,
    }, {
      display: false,
      stacked: true,
      id: "bar-x-axis2",
      barThickness: 70,
      // these are needed because the bar controller defaults set only the first x axis properties
      type: 'category',
      categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      barPercentage: 0.9,
      gridLines: {
        offsetGridLines: true
      },
      offset: true
    }],
    yAxes: [
      {
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
    }]

  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

Does anyone know if this is possible with chartJS?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved this myself. You need to set yAxisID to each dataset, and then define which will be stacked and which one isn't.

Here's the code:

```
var data = {
  labels: ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "First",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [10, 20, 30],
    xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
    yAxisID: "bar-y-axis1"
  },
  {
    label: "Second",
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [5, 7, 9],
    xAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
    yAxisID: "bar-y-axis1"
  },
  {
    label: "Third",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [5, 30, 35],
    xAxisID: "bar-x-axis2",
    yAxisID: "bar-y-axis2"
  }]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      id: "bar-x-axis1",
      barThickness: 30,
    }, {
      display: false,
      stacked: true,
      id: "bar-x-axis2",
      barThickness: 70,
      // these are needed because the bar controller defaults set only the first x axis properties
      type: 'category',
      categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      barPercentage: 0.9,
      gridLines: {
        offsetGridLines: true
      },
      offset: true
    }],
    yAxes: [
    {
        id: "bar-y-axis1",
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 40,
                autoSkip: false, 
      }
    },
      {
        id: "bar-y-axis2",
        stacked: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 40,
                    autoSkip: false,
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
            display: false
        }
    }]

  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

And a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1ret02b/2/

Comment: Please mark this as accepted as well if this works for you.